# React JSDoc functional component - I am getting the "inner" key when I document a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsdoc

When genereting the JSDoc of this component, I am getting the key "inner" next to my component definition. What does it mean? How can I remove it?

> Methods

> (inner) ActivityItemContainer() → {React.ReactElement}

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Properties received by the ActivityItemContainer component
 *
 * @typedef {object} ActivityItemContainerProps
 * @property {object} props - The ActivityItemContainer properties
 * @property {React.ReactElement} [props.children] - The ActivityItemContainer's children
 * @property {string} [props.icon] - The ActivityItemContainer's icon
 * @property {string} props.date - The ActivityItemContainer's date
 * @property {string} [props.backgroundColor] - The ActivityItemContainer's backgroundColor
 */

/**
 * Component for containing the user activity
 * with some design tweaks.
 *
 * @public
 * @type {React.FC<ActivityItemContainerProps>}
 * @returns {React.ReactElement} A fancy container
 * @example
 * const icon = {
 *   name: "ios-flash",
 *   type: "ionicon",
 *   size: 25,
 *   color: "#FF8100"
 * };
 *
 * const date = "3 hours ago";
 *
 * return (
 *   <ActivityItemContainer icon={icon} date={date}>
 *     ...
 *   </ActivityItemContainer>
 * );
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function ActivityItemContainer({
  icon,
  date,
  backgroundColor,
  children,
}) { ... }
```

Also, the following function is giving the same result to me:

```
/**
 * @private
 * @function areActivityItemContainerPropsEqual
 * @param {object} prevProps Previous component's props
 * @param {object} nextProps Next component's props
 * @returns {boolean} Returns true if the component's date remains intact between renders. Otherwise, it returns false.
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function areActivityItemContainerPropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.date === nextProps.date;
}
```

> (private, inner) areActivityItemContainerPropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) → {boolean}

Note: This is my file header:

```
/**
 * @author ...
 * @file Container for activity items.
 * @copyright ...
 * @license MIT
 * @module components/Activity
 * @exports {React.FC<ActivityItemContainerProps>} ActivityItemContainer
 */
```